# Not able to find image with <i> tag in protractor test

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor

I have the below for which i am writing the protractor test. i need to get the tooltip text from the  tag.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in errorData" class="errorData">
    <td>{{row.number}}</td>
    <td>{{row.road.data}}
        <i ng-if="row.road.errorCode" tooltip="{{row.road.errorCode | translate}}" class="icon-exclamation error"></i>
    </td>
    <td>{{row.desc.data}}
        <i ng-if="row.desc.errorCode" tooltip="{{row.desc.errorCode | translate}}" class="icon-exclamation error"></i>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Protractor test:

```
    element.all(by.repeater('row in errorData')).each(function (data) {
        data.element(by.css('td:nth-child(2) i')).isDisplayed().then(function (displayed) {
            if (displayed) {
                console.log("image found")
            } else {
                console.log("image not found");
            }
        });
    });
```

The error i am getting is :

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("td:nth-child(2) i")
```

if i use only by.css('td:nth-child(2)) this works and i don't get any exception. Any idea on how to get the tooltip text or rather reach the image element.

Answer (score 0):

You need recent version of protractor to do this (1.3 or higher):

```
$$('tr.errorData').each(function(row){
  // Get the second column. Then extract all the i elements and
  // then get the tooltip attribute.
  row.$$('td').get(1).$$('i').getAttribute('tooltip').then(function(tooltipArray) {
    // Will contain one element, if present.
    tooltipArray[0]; // Here is your tooltip
  });
});
```

Let me know if it works